# Using database_cleaner, mongoid and active_admin causes specs to fail with ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, activeadmin

I have an existing project using mongoid, database_cleaner and rspec. I try to add active_admin, using the [active_admin patches available](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/26). ActiveAdmin assumes it is in an ActiveRecord project, most specifically via its dependence on the meta_search gem.

When I go to run my specs, they all fail with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
# ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The gem versions of the related libraries are as follows:

- activeadmin (0.4.2)
- database_cleaner (0.7.1)
- mongoid (2.4.5)
- meta_search (1.1.3)
- activerecord (3.2.1)

The file that the tests are failing on, `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb`:

```
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer and accept it; that's the preferred flow.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli I'd like to, but I need more points to do that, sadly. Feel free to copy-paste my solution in place =D

Comment: @dznz: There is no rep requirement for answering your own questions as far as I'm aware; only a period of waiting time.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, of course. I'm just a very impatient person =D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[moved from question]**

It appears that database_cleaner attempts to autodetect the ORMs available to it in [its initialization method](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/master/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb)

This can be pre-empted by changing the `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb` file like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  end
end
```

Calling the `[]` method in [configuration](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/master/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb) overrides the autodetect such that ActiveRecord is no longer added.

Another workaround would have been to re-add a `config/database.yml` file with a sqlite3 configuration that the rest of the application ignored. Thankfully that isn't necessary.